# Unable to execute a pthread program in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv

I have written a C++ program that makes use of both openCV and Pthreads.

The code is as below,

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int lowThreshold=0;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int kernel_size = 3;
int ratio = 3;

Mat img;
Mat display;
Mat temp;

void CannyThreshold()
{
    cvtColor(img, display, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(display, display, Size(1, 1), 1,1);

    Canny(display,display,lowThreshold,3);

    imshow("Canny",display);
}

void Hough()
{
    Mat dip = temp.clone(); 
    
    medianBlur(temp,temp,9);
    Canny(temp,display,50,200);

    vector<Vec2f> lines; // will hold the results of the detection
    HoughLines(display, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 150, 30, 0 ); // runs the actual detection    

    for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
    {
        float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line(dip, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, LINE_AA);
    }

    printf("Lines = %ld\n",lines.size());

    imshow("Hough",dip);

}

void * transform(void * param)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    namedWindow("Canny");
    createTrackbar("Min Threshold: ","Canny",&lowThreshold,max_lowThreshold);

    while(1)
    {
        cap.read(img);

        temp = img;

        CannyThreshold();
        Hough();

        waitKey(1);
    }

    cap.release();
}

int main()
{

    pthread_t transformThread;
    pthread_attr_t transformThread_attr;
    struct sched_param rt_param;

    pthread_attr_init(&transformThread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&transformThread_attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&transformThread_attr, SCHED_FIFO);

    int rt_max_prio = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
    int rt_min_prio = sched_get_priority_min(SCHED_FIFO);

    rt_min_prio += 1; //To avoid compiler error for unused variable

    rt_param.sched_priority = rt_max_prio - 10;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&transformThread_attr, &rt_param);

    int ret = pthread_create(&transformThread,&transformThread_attr,transform,NULL);

    if(ret !=0)
    {
        perror("pthread_create()");
    }

    void * res;

    pthread_join(transformThread,&res);

    return 0;
}
```

The make file that I have written is as follows,

```
    CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
SRCS = main.cpp
PROG = main
LIBS = -lrt
CPPLIBS= -L/usr/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lpthread -pthread

OPENCV = `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

$(PROG):$(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(SRCS) `pkg-config --libs opencv4` $(CPPLIBS)

clean: 
    rm -rf main
```

I am getting the following error when I execute the program (Not when I compile it).

pthread_create(): No such file or directory

How do I get past this issue? Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Isn't the program called main? PROG=main, CC -o ($PROG)

Comment: And when you use `strace` to run your program, what do you see?

Comment: Hey @John3136
I didn't quite understand your comment. Yes, the file name is main.cpp

Comment: Hey @SamVarshavchik
This is the output of strace, 


fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8402 (flags O_RDWR|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0
write(3, "pthread_create(): No such file o"..., 44pthread_create(): No such file or directory
) = 44
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f2e721b1000, 16384)           = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++

Comment: `On success, pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number`. It does not set `errno`. Thus `perror` is not useful and `strerror(err)` should be used.

Comment: No, that's not the"output of strace". That's just /some/ of the output of strace. Missing is the trace of the pthread_create syscall, itself. However it does raise the question of why the error is logged to some mysterious file descriptor 3 instead of standard error, file descriptor 2. That's something that you'll need to figure out based on the /complete/ strace information. I find it unlikely that the libraries getting linked with bother to shuffle around standard error, for some bizarre reason.